# MvvmCross: How to navigate from regular view to Mvvm viewmodel on Android?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am slowly migrating my app over to MvvmCross on Android.  I have not converted all Activities over to ViewModels yet.  Therefore, I need to navigate from an Mvvm-controlled Activity to a regular Activity.  To do this, I made my own Presenter and intercepted the Show method and did my own StartActivity.  That seemed to work.  However, now I need to go the other direction and have my regular Activity go back to the original Mvvm-controlled Activity.  I tried just doing a StartActivity on the ViewModel using CLEAR_TOP flag, but I got an error:

```
"Null Extras seen on Intent when creating ViewModel - this should not happen - have you tried to navigate to an MvvmCross View directly?"
```

How can I go back to the original Mvvm-controlled activity from a regular Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple...

To go back from any standard Android `Activity`, you can simply ask the `Activity` to close using `Finish()`

---

But beyond that...

If instead you want to go forwards to an MvvmCross `View`, then you need to know a little about MvvmCross internals: in particular about how MvvmCross navigation conceptually happens between `ViewModels` rather than between `Activities`, `Pages` or `UIViewControllers`.

If you want to go forwards to a new `ViewModel`, then you can do this using the `IMvxViewDispatcher` singleton - how to do this is shown in [Show view from non-view/viewmodel in mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662969/show-view-from-non-view-viewmodel-in-mvvmcross/16664148#16664148)

If you then later want to go back from the current `ViewModel`, then you can try calling `Close(this)` within the `ViewModel` - by default, on Android this will map to `Finish()`, on Touch to `PopViewController`, on WpDev to `GoBack()`

Comment: I can try Finish in the example I provided and I am sure that will work.  However, what if I had a whole stack of regular views and I wanted to go back to the very first Activity which was Mvvm-based?  That is why I was trying to use CLEAR_TOP originally.  What would you suggest in that case?  Finish would only go to the previous regular activity, but I want to go back to the top.  I will put what I came up with below as an answer that seems to work, but is a hack as I had to use a special string MvxLaunchData.

Comment: unusual situations are what custom presenters and presentation hints are there for. I'd expect you'd have to code that behavior on each target platform with or without mvx

Comment: I tried the technique described in the question you referenced above.  It works great except for one thing.  On iOS, it seems that when the Presenter calls CreateView, a new instance is always created.  Is that intended?  Before I started using MvvmCross, I kept a reference to my first ViewController (the Login screen) so that I could show it again later after logout.  Using this new technique of grabbing the view dispatcher and showing my LoginViewModel, a second instance of the Login view controller is created which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry. I don't follow you. I think you're making some mental leaps from the Q&A here to the code you're working on. It feels like you're architecting lots of stuff - which I'm very happy for you to do - but I have enough trouble understanding code from an editor, let alone understanding it from comments on here. If you want to cache views, viewmodels and/or pokemon-cards, then please do - it's your app.

Comment: I will post a more general question on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work, but is a hack since I use a special string "MvxLaunchData".

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,typeof(LoginView));
i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer> ();
MvxViewModelRequest request = MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest (typeof(LoginViewModel));
i.PutExtra ("MvxLaunchData", converter.Serializer.SerializeObject(request));
StartActivity(i);
```

I will try the method shown in the other question you referenced.