# MvvmCross: Hybrid Xamarin.Forms and Android Activity Application

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms, view-model-pattern

Being new to MvvmCross I've decided to create a small Xamarin.Forms app. I have a `MainPage.xaml` tied to its ViewModel `MainViewModel.cs` which is displayed first. I have a `FirstView.axml` located in the droid project along with its activity. The associated ViewModel is located in the Core project along side the MainViewModel and is named `FirstViewModel.cs`

Upon clicking a navigate button I want MvvmCross to display the `FirstView.axml` layout and bind to the VM. However,

Whenever the command is invoked I get

```
03-10 10:11:38.704 D/ViewRootImpl(18964): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
mvx:Diagnostic: 17,87 Showing ViewModel FirstViewModel
03-10 10:11:38.854 I/mono-stdout(18964): mvx:Diagnostic: 17,87 Showing ViewModel FirstViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 17,87 Showing ViewModel FirstViewModel
mvx:Error: 17,91 Failed to create ContentPage FirstPage
03-10 10:11:38.894 I/mono-stdout(18964): mvx:Error: 17,91 Failed to create ContentPage FirstPage
[0:] mvx:Error: 17,91 Failed to create ContentPage FirstPage
mvx:Error: 17,92 Skipping request for FirstViewModel
03-10 10:11:38.904 I/mono-stdout(18964): mvx:Error: 17,92 Skipping request for FirstViewModel
[0:] mvx:Error: 17,92 Skipping request for FirstViewModel`
```

Currently the project looks like this:

**Startup Activity**

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Hello MvvmCrossForms", MainLauncher = true)]
public class CrossFormsApp : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        //Init forms
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        InitialiseMvx();

        //Create mvxformsApp
        var mvxFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp();
        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter;

        //Assign the viewPresenter
        presenter.MvxFormsApp = mvxFormsApp;
        LoadApplication(mvxFormsApp);

        //Start mvxApp
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();
    }

    private void InitialiseMvx()
    {
        if (MvxSingleton<IMvxIoCProvider>.Instance == null)
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton(MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize());

        MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this.ApplicationContext)
                                .EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _inputString;

    public ICommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>()); }
    }

    public string InputString
    {
        get { return _inputString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _inputString, value); }
    }
}
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is the reverse of this: [MvvmCross: How to navigate from regular view to Mvvm viewmodel on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718946/mvvmcross-how-to-navigate-from-regular-view-to-mvvm-viewmodel-on-android)

Comment: You're trying to navigate from a Xamarin Forms page, to an Activity. By default mvvmcross knows how to navigate to a XForms page to another, of from an activity to another. Take a look at Presenters, I think you have to write your own

Comment: That much was already clear. However, the approach was the issue. Anyway - I got it working, although I'm not completely happy with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was defining a empty interface `IXFViewModel` which I implement on the `Forms` ViewModels. Then in my custom presenter I get a list of interfaces which the `MvxViewModelRequest.ViewModelType` implements.

If the type `IXFViewModel` is found in the list of interfaces, the custom presenter - which extends `MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter` - handles the presentation by calling `base.Show(request)`. If the `IXFViewModel` type is not found the custom presenter switches to an `MvxAndroidViewPresenter` to handle the view presentation.

The solution below:

**Bootstrap**

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    /// prefix ///

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = new XFDroidPresenter();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewPresenter>(presenter);
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

**The Custom Presenter**

```
public class XFDroidPresenter : MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter
{
    protected MvxAndroidViewPresenter DroidPresenter { get; set; }
    protected Activity Activity { get { return Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity; } }

    public XFDroidPresenter()
    {
        DroidPresenter = new MvxAndroidViewPresenter();
    }

    public override void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if(Activity.GetType() != typeof(CrossFormsApp))
        {
            DroidPresenter.ChangePresentation(hint);
            return;
        }

        base.ChangePresentation(hint);
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var implementedInterfaces = request.ViewModelType
                                           .GetInterfaces()
                                           .ToList();

        if (!implementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IXFViewModel)))
        {
            DroidPresenter.Show(request);
            return;
        }

        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

**The Launcher and Forms Activity**

```
[Activity(Label = "Hello MvvmCrossForms", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true)]
public class CrossFormsApp : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    private MvxAndroidLifetimeMonitor _lifeTimeMonitor;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        InitialiseMvx();

        var mvxFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp();
        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter;

        presenter.MvxFormsApp = mvxFormsApp;
        LoadApplication(mvxFormsApp);
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();

        _lifeTimeMonitor = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>() as MvxAndroidLifetimeMonitor;
        _lifeTimeMonitor.OnCreate(this);
    }

    private void InitialiseMvx()
    {
        if (MvxSingleton<IMvxIoCProvider>.Instance == null)
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton(MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize());

        MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this.ApplicationContext)
                                .EnsureInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart ();
        _lifeTimeMonitor.OnStart(this);
    }

    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart ();
        _lifeTimeMonitor.OnRestart(this);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume ();
        _lifeTimeMonitor.OnResume(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy ();
        _lifeTimeMonitor.OnDestroy(this);
    }
}
```

**The Interface and ViewModel**

```
public interface IXFViewModel
{
}

public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel, IXFViewModel
{
    private string _inputString;

    public ICommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => Close(this)); }
    }

    public string InputString
    {
        get { return _inputString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _inputString, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In MvvmCross, the ViewPresenter is the component, that handles the navigation between the views.

So we have to create our own

- that inherits from `MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter`, because we have a Forms App
- redirects non-Forms calls of

  - `ChangePresentation` (which is usally used for Close())
  - `Show`

  to a ViewPresenter that handles Activities (`MvxAndroidViewPresenter`)
- a list of non-Forms ViewModels (`_androidViews`)

```cs
class HybridDroidViewPresenter : MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter
{
    private readonly MvxAndroidViewPresenter _androidPesenter;
    private readonly List<Type> _androidViews;
    protected Activity Activity => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;


    public HybridDroidViewPresenter()
    {
        _androidPesenter = new MvxAndroidViewPresenter();
        _androidViews = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof (FirstViewModel)
        };
    }

    public override void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        if (Activity.GetType() != typeof (MainActivity))
        {
            // if we are not on the Forms Activity, we assume, we are on an Android Activity
            _androidPesenter.ChangePresentation(hint);
            return;
        }

        base.ChangePresentation(hint);
    }

    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (_androidViews.Contains(request.ViewModelType))
        {
            _androidPesenter.Show(request);
            return;
        }

        base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

To register our new ViewPresenter, we have to override `CreateViewPresenter` in our Setup

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    // ...

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = new HybridDroidViewPresenter();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewPresenter>(presenter);
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

Our ViewPresenter and the `MvxAndroidViewPresenter` needs `IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity`. So we need to let it know about the life cycle of our `MainActivity`. This can be done via `IMvxAndroidActivityLifetimeListener` and modifying the Activity as follows:

```cs
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity
    : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    private IMvxAndroidActivityLifetimeListener _lifetimeListener;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        var mvxFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp();
        LoadApplication(mvxFormsApp);

        var presenter = (MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter) Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>();
        presenter.MvxFormsApp = mvxFormsApp;

        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();
        _lifetimeListener = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidActivityLifetimeListener>();
        _lifetimeListener.OnCreate(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        _lifetimeListener.OnDestroy(this);
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        _lifetimeListener.OnViewNewIntent(this);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        _lifetimeListener.OnResume(this);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        _lifetimeListener.OnPause(this);
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        _lifetimeListener.OnStart(this);
    }

    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        _lifetimeListener.OnRestart(this);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _lifetimeListener.OnStop(this);
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

Now we are able to navigate to our `FirstViewModel` via

```cs
ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>()
```

and the FirstActivity looks like a normal MvvMCross Android Activity and sets the `FirstView.axml` as `ContentView`.

```cs
[Activity(Label = "FirstActivity")]
public class FirstActivity : MvxActivity<FirstViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
    }
}
```

**Be aware of:**

- With this you can't navigate to a Forms-View form a non-Forms View (but to non-Forms Views), except going back via `Close()`, or the back button
- There might be some issues left with the lifecycle (e.g. tombstoning)
- The devs of MvvMCross are unhappy with the Forms-Support of MvvMCross, so there might be some breaking changes on the Forms Presenter

Comment: I'm inclined to go with your solution since it derives from `MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter` implying it will hold the binding context already. However, I'll have to do some dev before I'm convinced.