# MvvmCross + Deep Linking

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement deep linking ability using `xamarin + mvvmcross`,

the deep-linking configuration in either plist/manifest are already done and working.

What i'm trying achieve is that when either my app is running or not, i would like my main view model to handle the params sent by the deep-link in it's `InitFromBundle` (`IMvxBundle bundle`) method (my Main view model is always alive while the app is running).

While in android it's fairly easy to achieve by overriding the `TriggerFirstNavigate` in the splash screen activity and overriding the `IMvxAppStart` Start method, i'v gone through the `mvvmcross` source to see how it's done in `Xamarin.iOS` and still no luck.

When my ios app is opened from a deep-link, the `InitFromBundle` (`IMvxBundle bundle`) method do handle the url params, but when i click on deep-link while my app is alive, it bring the app to the front but doesnt call the `InitFromBundle` method.

What i did already is check in the apple developers about how it works, as can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW21):

My case can be seen in Figure 6-2 in the above link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, but based on the docs I would imagine you need to override `HandleOpenURL` inside the appdelegate.cs. You might then want to use a messenger to alert your application that a new url has been requested, or follow the answer here to [navigate to a view model from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662969/show-view-from-non-view-viewmodel-in-mvvmcross/16664148#16664148).

e.g.

```
public override bool HandleOpenURL (UIApplication application, NSUrl url)
{
    if (url != null)
    {
        //do navigation or message notification here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I'v already tried that method through overriding the OpenUrl method.
In android for example, when clicking on deep-link intent url causes a view to be re-created and therefore
initializing the viewmodel, in iOS as i understand the view isn't re-created and thats where i am looking
for the right place to do viewmodel initialization using InitFromBundle (IMvxBundle bundle) method in the ViewModel (does that makes sense?).

Comment: @Ross's answer looks good to me. When I've done this I've normally intercepted the "open url" and then navigated the application to a new `ViewModel`. If you want instead to perform some processing within the  existing shown `ViewModel` then you probably just need to send it a `Message` or to call a method on it directly.