# How to share ShowViewModel class in ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am developing a Xamarin mobile app using MVVM Cross.  There are two ViewModels which are doing same thing i.e. showing a dialog using the code below:

```cs
var register = await UserDialogHelper.RaiseNotRegisteredAsync (UserDialogs);
        if (register) {
            ShowViewModel<WebViewModel> (new
                {
                    url = Urls.RegisterPage,
                    title = "Register",
                });
        }
```

I tried moving this code to static class but unable to resolve ShowViewModel.  Can anyone suggest how to resolve ShowViewModel in non-viewmodel class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have methods or properties to share between the same viewmoels. You can just implement a base viewmodel. And the other ones just inherit from this base viewmodel. Like following example:

```cs
public abstract class MyBaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Your code
        var register = await UserDialogHelper.RaiseNotRegisteredAsync (UserDialogs);
        if (register) {
            ShowViewModel<WebViewModel> (new
            {
                url = Urls.RegisterPage,
                title = "Register",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And then your viewmodels look like this:

```cs
public class MyFirstViewModel : MyBaseViewModel
{

}
```

Inside this `MyFirstViewModel` you can call the base method `MyMethod`. And so on...

**Edit**

If you want to navigate from outside a view/viewmodel: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664148/2653134) from Stuart or [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34060336/2653134) from @SergioZgz

Comment: I wanted  to have a shared class, static class with methods to raise dialogs.

Comment: I have edited my answer. But I think, my way with the inheritance should be your goal

Answer (score 0):

ShowViewModel comes from MvxNavigatingObject if your class doesn't inherited it you cannot use it.

You could something like this in a class than is not a MvxViewModel:

```cs
var viewDispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();
viewDispatcher.ShowViewModel(new MvxViewModelRequest(
                                                vmtype,
                                                parameterBundle,
                                                presentationBundle,
                                                requestedBy));
```

But I think that answer from Joehl is the correcty way :)